# Loss drops sharply at the beginning

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I use a transformer model to make some predictions similar to time series classification. The model consists of some embedding layers, multihead attention and dense layers. Why does the model loss decrease sharply at the beginning and the validation loss gradually?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @TimI would expect both losses to be close to each other.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Also, this is just 50 epochs, I don't know how many would be needed to achieve decent performance. Looking at the tend, in 1k epochs the lines would be nearly parallel and the difference at the start would be hard to notice.

Comment: @Tim Is possible to explain why loss drops sharply at start and model reaches maximum accuracy?

Comment: The problem is easy enough for the model, but it needs more training to be able to generalize outside of the training data. But without more details, access to your data and the code this would be a guessing game.